FORTRAN 77 BLAS functions have more arguments now?
When compiling an R package I have used successfully for years, I have suddenly started to get error messages that I had not seen before.  In particular, it seems as though the functions in the FORTRAN BLAS libraries now have more arguments than they used to.  For example, I am told that dgemv, which previously had 11 arguments, now seems to expect 12.
   matrix.c:44:83: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 12, have 11
         F77_CALL(dgemv)(transa, &nrx, &ncx, &alpha, x, &nrx, y, &ncy, &beta, z, &ncy);

I cannot find any documentation for these new functions (if indeed they exist), so I am rather stuck.
The code is in C, but as you can see it calls the FORTRAN 77 code for dgemv, which multiplies a matrix by a vector.  Below is an MWE.  Use this in a C file:
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <R_ext/Applic.h> /* array.c says need for dgemm */
#include <R_ext/Lapack.h> /* array.c says need for dgemm */

/* following copied from array.c */
void matprod(double *x, int nrx, int ncx,
             double *y, int nry, int ncy, double *z, double alpha, double beta)
{
  char *transa = "N";

  F77_CALL(dgemv)(transa, &nrx, &ncx, &alpha, x, &nrx, y, &ncy, &beta, z, &ncy);
}

and then use a function such as this in an R file:
mp <- function (x, y) {
  ## get dimensions
  dX <- dim(x)
  ly <- length(y)

  ## set up output
  z <- numeric(dX[1])

  ## perform the matrix multiplication
  matprod(as.numeric(x), as.integer(dX[1]), as.integer(dX[2]),
          as.numeric(y), as.integer(ly), 1L,
          as.numeric(z), 1.0, 0.0)

  return(z)
}

The full error message I receive on compilation is:
── R CMD INSTALL ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  installing *source* package ‘testMWE’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)’
   using C++ compiler: ‘Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)’
   using SDK: ‘MacOSX11.3.sdk’
   clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++17 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/opt/R/x86_64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   clang -arch x86_64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/opt/R/x86_64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c testMWE.c -o testMWE.o
   testMWE.c:13:79: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 12, have 11
     F77_CALL(dgemv)(transa, &nrx, &ncx, &alpha, x, &nrx, y, &ncy, &beta, z, &ncy);
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^
   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/BLAS.h:107:1: note: 'dgemv_' declared here
   F77_NAME(dgemv)(const char *trans, const int *m, const int *n,
   ^
   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/RS.h:81:24: note: expanded from macro 'F77_NAME'
   #define F77_NAME(x)    F77_CALL(x)
                          ^
   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/RS.h:77:22: note: expanded from macro 'F77_CALL'
   # define F77_CALL(x)    x ## _
                           ^
   <scratch space>:83:1: note: expanded from here
   dgemv_
   ^
   1 error generated.
   make: *** [testMWE.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘testMWE’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/hy/gbflvvdd5935l261dv4gtf900000gn/T/RtmpVM5ny2/devtools_install_b83f5e2c276a/testMWE’
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'R' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---

My system details:

Mac running Sonoma 14.6.1
RStudio Version 2024.09.0+375 (2024.09.0+375)

Of course, the explanation may be something completely different to what I have presumed here.
I have tried to find documentation for these BLAS functions, but to no avail.  I have also tried to find the new functions on my computers, also fruitlessly.

You are talking about Fortran functions and pointing to a Fortran function doc, but the code is C and the error is from a C compiler! If your C compiler complains that the number of arguments is wrong, you have to consult the docs for whichever C interface you are using in C. What does the F77_CALL macro actually do?

Check the header you are using /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/BLAS.h.

@VladimirFГероямслава It is something else: R manages the interface and alters the call to accommodate passing character length as well.  See my answer with a link to more documentation.

@AdaLovelace I do not see how that is "something else".

Because the documentation for what is implemented in that header is not in that header.  But in the section of the manual I referenced.  The header is essentially incomprehensible ("what are FCLEN and FCONE for ?") with the documentation.

This a relatively recent change from R 4.3.0 released 1 1/2 years ago.  Packages on CRAN all received 'nagging' emails asking to please fix.  The intent, as so often, is actually good as this deals with an improved way to communicate via character variables. See Section 6.6.1 Fortran Character Strings in WRE and its discussion of USE_FC_LEN_T and FCONE.  As I recall you simply add FCONE to the end of your function call after first defining it as needed
#ifndef FCONE
# define FCONE
#endif

change to
F77_CALL(dgemv)(transa, &nrx, &ncx, &alpha, x, &nrx, y, 
                &ncy, &beta, z, &ncy FCONE);

and everything should then 'just work'.

Interesting to note that the final argument doesn't require commas

Because with an 'implicit comma' and an 'empty FCONE definition' it will compiler under older R, and having FCONE defined under recent / current R allows the enhancement to also pass character length to pass.
